# int type and use it like "flags" in c

Tags: c, gcc, int

I've created a structure called panel which render in OpenGL,works fine,but I want to add this to panel:

```
int flags;
```

then I define this in header :

```
#define PANEL_TITLE    0x0001
#define PANEL_MOVEABLE 0x0002
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0003
```

to use the flags value like this:

```
panel.flags = PANEL_TITLE | PANEL_MOVEABLE;
```

instead of have a lot :(which looks not good)

```
bool panel_has_title;
bool panel_moveable;
bool panel_shadow;
```

then check bool value,instead I can just have single int to achieve same result.I have read a lot open source stuff,that use flags,like the code above.
however my problem is it doesn't work,when I check the flags with:

```
panel.flags = PANEL_TITLE | PANEL_MOVEABLE;
if(panel.flags & PANEL_TITLE) //this one works
{

}
if(panel.flags & PANEL_MOVEABLE) //this one doesn't work
{
  //not gets called
}
```

---

edit:
ok,now I've change it to

```
#define PANEL_TITLE    0x0002
#define PANEL_MOVEABLE 0x0004
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0008
```

are they intersect with each other again?
the new problem is if I set

```
panel.flags = PANEL_TITLE;
```

then every functions inside of it gets called

```
if(panel.flags & PANEL_TITLE)  
{
  //called which is normal
}
if(panel.flags & PANEL_MOVEABLE)  
{
  //called ..
}
if(panel.flags & PANEL_SHADOW)  
{
  //called ..
}
```

is it normal?

Comment: It's odd. It should work. PANEL_SHADOW should be 0x0004 (a separate bit, not the combination of TITLE and MOVEABLE?) Perhaps this is not your exact code?

Comment: could you show the code inside the first `if`, you might have changed the `panel.flags` value in there, hence it won't meet the 2nd `if`

Comment: I don't understand why the both answers are mentioning the value of the third flag. This is right, but the OP's example doesn't include `PANEL_SHADOW`...

Comment: What do you mean by called ? it's normal that this line will be executed, but it shouldn't go inside the if body...

Comment: I meant the function inside if gets called,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the bitmasks intersect with each other.
e.g. (simplefied for 8 bit)

```
#define PANEL_TITLE    0x0001 // 0b00000001
#define PANEL_MOVEABLE 0x0002 // 0b00000010
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0003 // 0b00000011
```

What you want is this:

```
#define PANEL_TITLE    0x0001 // 0b00000001
#define PANEL_MOVEABLE 0x0002 // 0b00000010
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0004 // 0b00000100
```

edit to your edit:

you don't set them like that, you set them with:

```
panel.flags |= PANEL_TITLE;
```

And for the last problem, I can't see anything wrong at first sight, try to step over it with a debugger and output the variable, that will give you a much clearer view of the problem

Comment: "you don't set them like that, you set them with:" -> What is the difference here ? In both cases, the bits of `PANEL_TITLE` will be setted.

Comment: True, but it's just very bad to do that. you don't know what other flags you clear by doing that

Comment: In this case, when one sets them like `flags=BITMASK` one can be sure that the problem is not that the flags are uninitialized and contain the bit 4 (or 8) in SHADOW. That would explain case #3.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define PANEL_TITLE    0x0001
#define PANEL_MOVEABLE 0x0002
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0003
```

When you define flags, they should not intersect. With your definition

```
PANEL_SHADOW == PANEL_MOVEABLE | PANEL_TITLE
```

is true.Did you meant it? Rather use a different bit, like

```
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0004
```

Print the values of `panel.flags & XXX`. Should be different from 0. The error is probaly somewhere else (do you modify the `panel.flags`?)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not normal. It's supernatural (just kidding...)

```
$ cat >pan.c && gcc pan.c && ./a.exe
#define PANEL_TITLE    0x0002
#define PANEL_MOVEABLE 0x0004
#define PANEL_SHADOW   0x0008
struct {int flags;} panel;
int main(){
  panel.flags = PANEL_TITLE | PANEL_MOVEABLE;
  if (panel.flags & PANEL_TITLE) printf("Hep\n");
  if (panel.flags & PANEL_MOVEABLE) printf("Hop\n");
  if (panel.flags & PANEL_SHADOW) printf("Hip\n");
}
```

Outputs as expected. It's not hip.

```
Hep
Hop
```

As are all the three variations in the modified question.

No suggested answer explains the claims. And while it's not necessarily right to have PANEL_SHADOW 0x0003, it's necessarily not wrong. In those cases though, one just typically declares:

```
#define PANEL_SHADOW (PANEL_TITLE | PANEL_MOVEABLE)
```

... to indicate that this indeed is the purpose.

Is your "panel" somehow mapped to a volatile memory?
Does the function alter it?
Have you #defined 0x0002 to mean something completely different?